# Type warning for Serial.printf macro

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++, platformio

I'm using this Macro in my platform.io code to be able to activate / deactivate all Serial prints centrally:

```
// DEBUG_PRINTF 
// Print string / value in new line with millis timestamp, function name + line number and message
// Usage: DEBUG_PRINTF("Printf Parameter: %s - %d \n", stringvar, value);
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(fmt, ...) \
   do                          \
   {                           \
      Serial.printf("%d: %s:%zu - " fmt, millis(), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__); \
   } while (0)
```

This works quite well, except for a lot of compiler warnings about wrong argument types:

```c
server\src\wifi.cpp:85:3: note: in expansion of macro 'DEBUG_PRINTF'
   DEBUG_PRINTF("[INFO] Starting WIFI Access Point with SSID: %s\n", AP_SSID);
   ^
server\lib\DebugUtils/DebugUtils.h:54:94: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
       Serial.printf("%d: %s:%zu - " fmt, millis(), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__); \
                                                                                              ^
```

The corresponding code looks like this:

```c
  // Create WIFI Access Point
  DEBUG_PRINTF("[INFO] Starting WIFI Access Point with SSID: %s\n", AP_SSID);
```

`AP_SSID` is a `static const char`

The warning occurs at every place i currently use the Macro, no matter what type of variable i pass into it.
Is there any way to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: You missed to escape the line endings using a \. Also the watning is pretty clear about the argument types expected for the `%d` formatting placeholder.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Thanks for the answer!  
The line endings of the macro are escaped with a \ if that is what you mean.  
The `%d` formatting placeholder is used for the millis() function and this should be correct i guess?

Comment: I'd guess that `millis()` might return an `unsigned` value (requiring `%u`). But check that from the arduino-c++ docs please, I am no expert with their library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Oh my god, thank you so much! That was indeed the problem!  
Changed it to `Serial.printf("%ul: %s:%d - " fmt, millis(), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);` and everything is working now...  
I was so confused because the error always said something about the third argument.  
**Vielen Dank, einen schönen Abend und viele Grüße aus Mittelfranken!**

Comment: Immer gerne, mia Bayern hoit'n z'samm ;-) Du kannts't a eig'ne Antwort schreim, wenns'd as scho aussi hast ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @πάνταῥεῖ i solved the problem:

The compiler warning was due to the `millis()` function returning an `unsigned long` type.
The macro now looks like this and works fine without any warnings:

```cpp
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(fmt, ...)                                                                    \
   do                                                                                             \
   {                                                                                              \
      Serial.printf("%lu: %s:%d - " fmt, millis(), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
   } while (0)
```

Example usage:

```cpp
DEBUG_PRINTF("[INFO] Webserver running: http://%d.%d.%d.%d:%d\n", ESP_IP[0], ESP_IP[1], ESP_IP[2], ESP_IP[3], HTTP_PORT);
```